# SED find line with first pattern then insert a line before line with second pattern

Tags: sed

Sample file1:

```
//MODIFICATIONS:  
//comment  
//comment  
//  
</IF>
```

Sample file2:

```
MODIFICATIONS:
comment without leading //
comment without leading //
</IF>
```

Sample file3

```
MODIFICATIONS:
comment without leading //
comment without leading //

</IF>
```

I need to update 300+ files that look like variations of the above. I think the easiest solution would be a SED command that:

- looks for a line ending with "MODIFICATIONS:" (I've confirmed that "MODIFICATIONS:" only ever occurs once in each file
- then looks for the next `</IF`> (there will be many, I only want the first) and sticks a new comment line in before this line.

Ideally this would be able to be run against files not containing "MODIFICATIONS:" and would do nothing. The files are in a multiple nested folders so running recursively would help a lot.

I'm on Mac OS but also have access to Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for the first quotation mark? And what is the comment line that you want to insert?

Comment: Sorry, messed up the formatting. Looking for the </IF>

Comment: What exactly is the comment line you want to insert?

Comment: Comment line is "Patch123 29\05\2015  A. User Migrated to 141"

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '/MODIFICATIONS:/{:l;n;/<\/IF>/{a\
comment
b};bl}' input
```

*Gives:*

```
//MODIFICATIONS:  
//comment  
//comment  
//  
</IF>  
comment
```

Comment: Sorry, "comment" is a place holder and differs in every file. I really think it needs to look for `</if`> and put something before it.

Comment: your question is not clear on the desired output. Do you want to put the same comment to every file but the comment will be different for each batch?

Comment: The comment to insert is "Patch123 29\05\2015 A. User Migrated to 141" this needs to appear on the line before the "`</IF`>" that occurs after "MODIFICATIONS:"